# Trying to find sets of numbers with all distinct sums; help optimizing algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, optimization

I was recently trying to write an algorithm to solve a math problem I came up with (long story how I encountered it): basically, I wanted to come up with sets of P distinct integers such that given a number, there is at most one way of selecting G numbers from the set (repetitions allowed) which sum to that number (or put another way, there are not two distinct sets of G integers from the set with the same sum, called a "collision"). For example, with P, G = 3, 3, the set (10, 1, 0) would work, but (2, 1, 0) wouldn't, since 1+1+1=2+1+0.

I came up with an algorithm in Python that can find and generate these sets, but when I tried it, it runs extremely slowly; I'm pretty sure there is a much more optimized way to do this, but I'm not sure how. The current code is also a bit messy because parts were added organically as I figured out what I needed.

The algorithm starts with these two functions:

```
import numpy

def rec_gen_list(leng, index, nums, func):
    if index == leng-1: #list full
        func(nums)
    else:
        nextMax = nums[index-1];
        for nextNum in range(nextMax)[::-1]: # nextMax-1 to 0
            nums[index] = nextNum;
            rec_gen_list(leng, index+1, nums, func)
            
def gen_all_lists(leng, first, func):
    nums = np.zeros(leng, dtype='int')
    nums[0] = first
    rec_gen_list(leng, 1, nums, func)
```

Basically, this code generates all possible lists of distinct integers (with maximum of "first" and minimum 0) and applies some function to them. rec_gen_list is the recursive part; given a partial list and an index, it tries every possible next number in the list less than the last one, and sends that to the next recursion. Once it gets to the last iteration (with the list being full), it applies the given function to the completed list. Note that I stop before the last entry in the list, so it always ends with 0; I enforce that because if you have a list that doesn't contain 0, you can subtract the smallest number from each one in the list to get one that does, so I force them to have 0 to avoid duplicates and make other things I'm planning to do more convenient.

gen_all_lists is the wrapper around the recursive function; it sets up the array and first iteration of the process and gets it started. For example, you could display all lists of 4 distinct numbers between 7 and 0 by calling it as gen_all_lists(4, 7, print). The function included is so that once the lists are generated, I can test them for collisions before displaying them.

However, after coming up with these, I had to modify them to fit with the rest of the algorithm. First off, I needed to keep track of if the algorithm had found any lists that worked; this is handled by the foundOne and foundNew variables in the updated versions. This probably could be done with a global variable, but I don't think it's a significant issue with the slowdown.

In addition, I realized that I could use backtracking to significantly optimize this: if the first 3 numbers out of a long list are something like (100, 99, 98...), that already causes a collision, so I can skip checking all the lists generated from that. This is handled by the G variable (described before) and the test_no_colls function (which tests if a list has any collisions for a certain value of G); each time I make a new sublist, I check it for collisions, and skip the recursive call if I find any.

This is the result of these modifications, used in the current algorithm:

```
import numpy

def rec_test_list(leng, index, nums, G, func, foundOne):
    if index == leng - 1: #list full
        foundNew = func(nums)
        foundOne = foundOne or foundNew
    else:
        nextMax = nums[index-1];
        for nextNum in range(nextMax)[::-1]: # nextMax-1 to 0
            nums[index] = nextNum;
            # If already a collision, don't bother going down this tree.
            if (test_no_colls(nums[:index+1], G)):
                foundNew = rec_test_list(leng, index+1, nums, G, func, foundOne)
                foundOne = foundOne or foundNew
    return foundOne
            
def test_all_lists(leng, first, G, func):
    nums = np.zeros(leng, dtype='int')
    nums[0] = first
    return rec_test_list(leng, 1, nums, G, func, False)
```

For the next two functions, test_no_colls takes a list of numbers and a number G, and determines if there are any "collisions" (two distinct sets of G numbers from the list that add to the same total), returning true if there are none. It starts by making a set that contains the possible scores, then generates every possible distinct set of G indices into the list (repetition allowed) and finds their totals. Each one is checked for in the set; if one is found, there are two combinations with the same total.

The combinations are generated with another algorithm I came up with; this probably could be done the same way as generating the initial lists, but I was a bit confused about the variable scope of the set, so I found a non-recursive way to do it. This may be something to optimize.

The second function is just a wrapper for test_no_colls, printing the input array if it passes; this is used in the test_all_lists later on.

```
def test_no_colls(nums, G):
    possiblePoints=set(()) # Set of possible scores.
    ranks = np.zeros(G, dtype='int')
    ranks[0] = len(nums) - 1 # Lowest possible rank.
    curr_ind = 0
    while True: # Repeat until break.
        if ranks[curr_ind] >= 0: # Copy over to make the start of the rest.
            if curr_ind < G - 1:
                copy = ranks[curr_ind]
                curr_ind += 1
                ranks[curr_ind] = copy
            else: # Start decrementing, since we're at the end. We also have a complete list, so test it.
                # First, get the score for these rankings and test to see if it collides with a previous score. 
                total_score = 0
                for rank in ranks:
                    total_score += nums[rank]
                if total_score in possiblePoints: # Collision found.
                    return False
                # Otherwise, add the new score to the list.
                possiblePoints.add(total_score)
                
                #Then backtrack and continue.
                ranks[curr_ind] -= 1
        else: 
            # If the current value is less than 0, we've exhausted the possibilities for the rest of the list, 
            # and need to backtrack if possible and start with the next lowest number.
            curr_ind -= 1;
            if (curr_ind < 0): # Backtracked from the start, so we're done.
                break
            else:
                ranks[curr_ind] -= 1 # Start with the next lowest number.
    # If we broke out of the loop before returning, no collisions were found.
    return True

def show_if_no_colls(nums, games):
    if test_no_colls(nums, games):
        print(nums)
        return True
    return False
```

These are the final functions that wrap everything up. find_good_lists wraps up test_all_lists more conveniently; it finds all lists ranging from 0 to maxPts of length P which have no collisions for a certain G. find_lowest_score then uses this to find the smallest possible maximum value of a list that works for a certain P and G (for example, find_lowest_score(6, 3) finds two possible lists with max 45, [45 43 34 19  3  0] and [45 42 26 11  2  0], with nothing that is all below 45); it also shows some timing data about how long each iteration took.

```
def find_good_lists(maxPts, P, G):
    return test_all_lists(P, maxPts, G, lambda nums: show_if_no_colls(nums, G))

from time import perf_counter

def find_lowest_score(P, G):
    maxPts = P - 1; # The minimum possible to even generate a scoring table.
    foundSet = False;
    while not foundSet:
        start = perf_counter()
        foundSet = find_good_lists(maxPts, P, G)
        end = perf_counter()
        print("Looked for {}, took {:.5f} s".format(maxPts, end-start))
        maxPts += 1;
```

So, this algorithm does seem to work, but it runs very slowly; when trying to run lowest_score(7, 3), for example, it starts taking minutes per iteration around maxPts in the 70s or so, even on Google Colab. Does anyone have suggestions for optimizing this algorithm to improve its runtime and time complexity, or better ways to solve the problem? I am interested in further exploration of this (such as filtering the lists generated for other qualities), but am concerned about the time it would take with this algorithm.

Comment: How many lists do you want?

Comment: @rici I'm looking for a faster way to do find_good_lists (given maxPts, P and G, find all lists that have the desired properties).